# Can I laminate pasta dough with meat?

Tags: meat, dough, pasta

I've seen a number of sites talk about laminating pasta dough with herbs and it looks lovely. But I haven't seen anything about doing this with meat. I assume you wouldn't want to do it with uncooked meat, but I feel like you could do with thin slices of cured or cooked meat.

1. Is it possible to laminate pasta dough with meat?
2. Has anyone done this before?

[image: pasta dough laminated with herbs]

Comment: What a cool idea! I've never seen it with herbs before either. That's going to get me to break out my pasta roller.

Comment: Isn't meat in 2 sheets of pasta called ravioli?

Comment: .. or lasagne..

Comment: Lasagne isn't laminated @Tetsujin, ravioli is.

Comment: tbh, if you consider one to be substrate & the other to be 'glue' then ravioli is a more perfect laminate. Ravioli has 'glued' edges but a filling breaking the laminate, unless you are considering a single surface laminate, like Formica, as opposed to the more traditional building terminology which would include glue-lam or plywood :P. (I'm not sure this is going to get us anywhere, though ;)

Comment: Ravioli is dough folded over meat. Laminating is when it's pressed together into a sheet again so the contents become part of the dough.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm very interesting idea.

You would need very thin flexible slices of meat of a consistent thickness, possibly tenderized. I can't see this being easily done at home unless you happen to have a meat slicer - or can access meats prepared like this.

I suspect that cured, readily sliced meats would work best in terms of consistency for the meat; something like [Prosciutto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosciutto) could work just fine, because it is thinly sliced and fairly consistent in thickness. It would perhaps work with sushi grade [Tuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuna) or other fairly firm fish (salmon) that can be sliced thinly - the only difficulty then would be cooking it, which would ruin the texture I think.

I don't think that raw meats would work well at all, though [carpaccio??](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpaccio) - it would be very difficult to slice them and you would have problems with contamination of your pasta machine, even if things went perfectly.

I can see some pretty interesting pasta coming out of this - imagine having alternating pieces of prosciutto with herb in a wide noodle, or even layered herb and meat.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but my hunch is that the fat in the meat (say prosciutto) will cause the layer to separate when cooked.  I would like to hear if someone has success.

Comment: @moscafj - good point, perhaps egg dip the meat beforehand?